# How to filter or search name and id & Cnic in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to filter data based on the table columns cnin,name,id.

```
public function Search(Request $request){
       $employee = $request->search;
       $empm = DB::table('users')
                     
                   ->where('name','LIKE',"%$employee%")
                   // ->where('cnic','LIKE',"%$employee%")
                   ->orWhere('cnic','LIKE','%employee%')
                   ->orWhere('id','LIKE','%employee%')
                   ->get();

                     return view('Users.markindexo',compact('empm'));}
```

Comment: Did you want to make a multiple parameter search filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$empm = DB::table('users')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$employee%");
        $query->orWhere('cnic','LIKE','%employee%');
        $query->orWhere('id','LIKE','%employee%');
    })->get();
               
return view('Users.markindexo',compact('empm'));
```